# CKEditor with "Univers LT Std 45 Light" font type

Tags: fonts, ckeditor

Could I please confirm whether CKEditor supports the font "Univers LT Std 45 Light". The reason is that after I updated my config as follows:

```
config.font_names = CKEDITOR.config.font_names + ';Univers LT Std 45 Light';
```

I do not see this font being applied in the editor, instead it defaults to "Arial". I also have this font installed in my PC (Windows\Fonts).

Am I using the correct font-name for this?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution I found for this problem.

In my case, a client had installed the font (otf) 'Univers LT Std 45 Light', so we needed to make this work. Unfortunately as explained in my first question, ckeditor was sanitising this font and defaulting to Arial. In order to avoid this and let ckeditor behaves correctly, you need to set the config as follows:

```
config.font_names = CKEDITOR.config.font_names + ';Univers 45 Light/Univers LT Std';
```

This is working fine for me now. I could not find any information about this font used in CKEditor, but I think i found my answer.

Hope this help anyone going through he same problem.

Martin